# Can I use data in a query in the Page Header of a Reporting Services report?

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services

I am pretty sure I cannot, but I would just like to double check - can I use data in a query in the Page Header of a Reporting Services report?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this answers my question for me:

[SQL Server Reporting Services: Report Header cannot show data fields](http://aleemkhan.wordpress.com/2007/02/25/sql-server-reporting-services-report-header-cannot-show-data-fields/)

Answer (score 1):

There is a little hack that you can do, although it's long winded. If you create a hidden report parameter that is loaded with the value you want in the header, then you can refer to the parameter (=Parameters!*MyParameterName*.Value) in the report Header/Footer.

Not great, but if you really need it then this should work.

Answer (score 0):

You tend to struggle doing this, as i think the header is created before any of the queries have actually been ran, so the data is not available

Comment: Thanks beakersoft, it appears that you can only show parameters or static text in the page header.